# not found object of type id

Tags: objective-c, snapchat

i am tying to make my own [SnapchatHax](https://github.com/unixpickle/SnapchatHax) and when i am tying to build the app i have a error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       property 'timeIntervalSince1970' not found on object of type 'id'   SnapchatHax (SnapchatHax\SnapchatHax)   C:\re\SnapchatHax-master\SnapchatHax\Snapchat\Internal\SCAPIRequest.m   14
```

here is the code that have the bug:

```
//  SCAPIRequest.m
//  SnapchatHax
//
//  Created by Alex Nichol on 12/17/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Alex Nichol. All rights reserved.
//

#import "SCAPIRequest.h"

@implementation SCAPIRequest

+ (NSString *)timestampString {\
    NSTimeInterval time = [NSDate date].timeIntervalSince1970;
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%llu", (unsigned long long)round(time * 1000.0)];
}
```

Thanks everyone

Comment: + (NSString *)timestampString {\ <---- see that \ ? maybe that is the case?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is

```
[NSDate date]
```

is returning a NSDate type of object and you have accessed timeIntervalSince1970 directly from it which of different type.
Use

```
NSTimeInterval value = ((NStimeInterval*)[anArray objectAtIndex:0]).aVariable;
```

Hope your problem will get solve

Thanks